# Объясните строчку кода

Tags: python, django

Объясните строчку кода :
`<a href="{% url 'by_rubric' rubric_id=rubrc.pk %}">...</a>`. Спасибо.

Comment: https://djbook.ru/rel3.0/intro/tutorial03.html#removing-hardcoded-urls-in-templates

Comment: https://djbook.ru/rel3.0/ref/templates/builtins.html#url

Answer (score 1):

Что ж, html-тег `<a></a>` указывает необходимость отображения содержимого тега в виде ссылки, `href=""` является атрибутом тега  и указывает адрес, куда необходимо переадресовать пользователя после нажатия на ссылку, `{% url 'by_rubric' rubric_id=rubrc.pk %}` – это стандартный тэг Django, который используется в шаблонах, чтобы при рендеринге страницы автоматически подставить адрес (например, google.com). В 'кавычках' указывается наименование пути, по которому django следует начать реверс (в файле urls.py: `path('contact/', views.contuct_us_view, name='contact-us')`). После идут параметры пути, которые необходимо передать. Очевидно, путь который вы попросили разобрать содержит захватываемые переменные и может иметь вид `path('contact/<rubric_id>/', views.contuct_us_view, name='contact-us')`